# Resolver error de interesados por cursos

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

estoy haciendo un CRUD de interesados y curso. Cada interesado puede interesarse por cualquier curso. Traigo todos los datos del curso y los interesados, pero luego en el html se pone todo en el primer curso. Necesito que cada interesado aparezca en la tabla de cada curso pero pone todo en el primer curso. Me parece que hay que cambiar algo aca en el javascript nada mas pero no me doy cuenta que

code_cursos.js:

```
this.listar_interesados_curso = (curso) => {
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("id_curso", curso.id_curso);
    fetch("../controllers/listado_interesados_curso.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: form,
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.interesados_por_curso.innerHTML += `
                <div class="row justify-content-center p-5 col-sm-10">
                    <div>
                        <h5>Curso: "${curso.nombre}"</h5>
                        <table class="table text-center">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Apellido</th>
                                    <th>Teléfono</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Dirección</th>
                                    <th>Localidad</th>
                                    <th>DNI</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="interesados_por_curso_datos"></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
            data.forEach((item) => {
                var form_interesados = new FormData();
                form_interesados.append("id_interesado", item['id_interesado']);
                fetch("../controllers/obtener_datos_interesados.php", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: form_interesados
                })
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        this.interesados_por_curso_datos = document.getElementById("interesados_por_curso_datos");
                        this.interesados_por_curso_datos.innerHTML += `
                            <tr>
                                <td>${data["id_interesado"]}</td>
                                <td>${data["nombre"]}</td>
                                <td>${data["apellido"]}</td>
                                <td>${data["telefono"]}</td>
                                <td>${data["email"]}</td>
                                <td>${data["direccion"] + " " + data["numero"]}</td>
                                <td>${data["localidad"]}</td>
                                <td>${data["dni"]}</td>
                            </tr>
                        `;
                    });
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: y como sabemos que cambiar si no has dicho en que falla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando siempre el mismo `id` y solo puede existir un único elemento con `id="interesados_por_curso_datos"`

#### Solución:

Podrías agregar al `id` de cada tabla de curso, el `curso_id` y así poder identificaras con un ID único.

Entonces:

- En la tabla del curso ID X, creamos el `<tbdoy>` así:

```js
`...<tbody id="interesados_por_curso_datos${curso.id_curso}"></tbody>`
```

- Cuando agregas los interesados, buscamos el `<tbody>` así:

```js
document.getElementById("interesados_por_curso_datos"+curso.id_curso)
```

#### Código:

```js
this.listar_interesados_curso = (curso) => {
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("id_curso", curso.id_curso);
  fetch("../controllers/listado_interesados_curso.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: form,
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.interesados_por_curso.innerHTML += `
        <div class="row justify-content-center p-5 col-sm-10">
            <div>
                <h5>Curso: "${curso.nombre}"</h5>
                <table class="table text-center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido</th>
                            <th>Teléfono</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Dirección</th>
                            <th>Localidad</th>
                            <th>DNI</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="interesados_por_curso_datos${curso.id_curso}"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>`;
      data.forEach((item) => {
        var form_interesados = new FormData();
        form_interesados.append("id_interesado", item['id_interesado']);
        fetch("../controllers/obtener_datos_interesados.php", {
          method: "POST",
          body: form_interesados
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            document.getElementById("interesados_por_curso_datos" + curso.id_curso).innerHTML += `
              <tr>
                  <td>${data["id_interesado"]}</td>
                  <td>${data["nombre"]}</td>
                  <td>${data["apellido"]}</td>
                  <td>${data["telefono"]}</td>
                  <td>${data["email"]}</td>
                  <td>${data["direccion"] + " " + data["numero"]}</td>
                  <td>${data["localidad"]}</td>
                  <td>${data["dni"]}</td>
              </tr>`;
          });
      })
    })
}
```